# Can pandas.open_csv() open more file types than just a .csv file?

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if I could open a different file extension than .csv even if it is formatted the same way?

For example I have a .key file that is being used as a cipher and it is using the .csv format, but I do not know if i can still open it.

Comment: If you mean `pandas.read_csv` then the answer is yes. There are no checks that the file path has a specific extension.

Comment: Give it a try. It'll work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes - the `read_csv()` method can definitely read other kind of files except csv. for example you can read txt file with `pd.read_csv()`. but pandas has a build in methods to read XLSX, html and other format... so is better to use a built-in method for the specific type you need.

**Source - pandas.read_csv documentation:**
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: **definitely**, not "defiantly".